# How upload image through dropdown menu?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration form and that contains a dropdown menu of categories. If some body picks a category "Medical" I want to upload a fixed image from root folder to database that assigned to MEDICAL. Likewise for "Religious", "Travel" etc. etc. Is it possible? Please help me.....

Comment: im going to assume that when you say root folder you mean the image is already on the server... If this is the case you don't need to upload the image, all you need to do is check for the "medical" option when the form is submitted. All you then do is store the filepath to the image on your server, in your database.

Comment: It is possible but the right solution depends on whether the dropdown menu a part of a larger form or not i.e are there other inputs in the form as the dropdown? Please confirm that

Comment: also @martswite makes a very valid point. You might not need to upload the images afterall.

Comment: Yes.. root folder means the image is already on the server. "All you then do is store the filepath to the image on your server, in your database." How is this possible?

Comment: Its not a larger form. There are other inputs in the form as the drop down.

Comment: @Saam I'll add an answer.... Bear with me

Answer (score 0):

So you have your images on your server. I will assume that they are in a folder called images. In that folder you have the image that you wish display for the medical selection. For the sake of this answer we will call it **medical.png**.

So for this example the setup on your server would look something like this.

```
htdocs/images/medical.png
```

Right now when medical is selected in the drop down and the form is submitted all you have to do is this. (I'll skip validation and simplify a bit so don't just use this raw)

```
<?php 

//Check for the medical selection
//Add other cases in here for your other selections
switch ($_POST['dropdown']) {
    case "Medical" :    
        $imgPath = "/images/medical.png";
        break;
}
```

Now i will also assume that you have a field in your database where you were originally going to store the image. All you now need to do store the $imgPath in that field. When you retrieve that data and need to display it you simply place the image path from the db into the src tag of an image field like so.

```
<img src="<?php echo $imgPathFromDb; ?>" />
```